# In what format are numbers represented in modern computers?

Tags: floating-point, binary

I have read about the representation of numbers in binary,Sign-Magnitude,Complement of 1,Complement of 2, IEEE 754 for floating points and how they can be implemented in circuits and my question is : what kind of standard of binary representation do modern computers use?

Answer (score 2):

For storage or networking protocols, things can be in all kinds of formats, depending on what's best to hold the data and how optimized the programmers deem it should be. You can find some wacky formats; for example, a protocol I wrote some months ago had the sign bit as the least significant bit, with base64 encoding. That way, negative integers don't take up excessive bytes unless they are actually very large numbers, whereas Two's Complement would fill out the entire field size with "-1". Google Protocol Buffers does a similar thing for that reason, using "ZigZag" encoding for signed numbers.

As for a more direct answer to the question: for everyday normal modern computing, Two's Complement is by far the most common internal representation for integers. I know that most computers have special flags and instructions to accommodate Two's Complement arithmetic, such as the "carry" flag for detecting overflows, and the "sign" flag for detecting if a result has the most significant bit set.

Things get a bit more tricky with floating point numbers, though IEEE 754 seems most common for computations. My floating point arithmetic knowledge is fairly dated, so this is welcome to any corrections. Last I checked (like 10 years ago), modern FPUs use "real" precision during calculation time--in that their registers are an 80-bit format, and then when storing data or retrieving results from the FPU, it's converted into single or double precision (32 or 64 bit) depending on the program.

Advanced modern software on modern CPUs also has access to more powerful floating point operations (SIMD - Single Instruction Multiple Data) meant to work on vectors or other complex mathematics where a lot of data crunching is needed (image filters, audio codecs, procedural generation, etc), but the registers used there are just multiple multiple instances of the common floating point formats or integers combined.

As pointed out in the comments, the SIMD instructions are becoming much more popular these days among floating point operations. They are far more powerful in terms of performance, and nearly every CPU these days (in the PC world/x86 architecture) do have access to at *least* the SSE2 instruction set (dated year 2000/the Pentium 4). I don't think software tends to favor precision over performance, and anything that actually requires high precision calculations is likely using custom arithmetic anyway (e.g. bank software does not use floating point operations so they don't lose any fractions of pennies to rounding errors--or more importantly, any pennies lost or gained in rounding are consistent across all machines).

Comment: Most of that's up-to-date, except that extended precision (the 80-bit floats you mentioned) is falling out of favor. On x86 and x64, modern compilers tend to use SSE registers for all floating point math, and that means no extended precision.

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks. One could even speculate that the old FPU instructions might be deprecated in the future, though maybe that's asking a lot from some software which depends on the precision.